# seleniumwire interceptor not catching 502 error

Tags: seleniumwire, httpinterceptor

I'm using seleniumwire to connect to a site and monitor specific request/response that are triggered by the site about once per second. Often these responses will contain an empty dataset, indicating there is no data to update, other times it will return only the data that has changed since the last request.

It's working fine, but we noted that it doesn't seem to catch 502 errors which *are* visible in the browser console.

It can happen that we're connected and are getting regular updates as expected with nice 200 status codes, but then some server issue occurs and those requests return a 502 error. The interceptor doesn't indicate anything at all (we're printing the status code) but simply sits there doing nothing, then the server reconnects and the interceptor picks up again and continues printing the 200 status code.

We really need to capture anything that's not a 200 response code so we can flag when we're not able to get updates.